# Preventing XSS for REST API

Tags: xss, rest

I have a spring REST API and a client project. Client projects' HTML page uses jquery ajax calls to fetch data from REST API using json or xml format. My question is to avoid XSS attacks on a web page, where should i perform encoding of user input data (i.e. untrusted data)? Currently i am encoding data into my REST Controller before returning the response. I am following OWASP XSS Prevention cheat sheet article. But since in my scenario, everything is ajax calls and data fetching from json and putting into html using jquery, not sure about where should user encoder to encode untrusted data. Is putting encoding in REST Controller is good option?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 30):

If the REST API purely returns JSON (and never HTML) then do the HTML escaping client-side, in JavaScript.

Whether the client's HTML page uses JQuery templating, or builds up HTML with calls to functions like `.html()` neither of these by default have XSS protection. One approach is for the client code to explicitly call an escaping function on all untrusted input. However, an approach I prefer is to use a JQuery plugin that does automatic escaping. Here are two approaches for this:

- [Making JQuery templates safe against HTML injection](http://mikesamuel.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/making-jquery-templates-safe-against.html)
- [Safe version of jQuery’s `.html()`](http://www.shafigullin.pro/XSS/jquery.html)

People may criticise this approach, saying "you can't rely on client-side control for security". That criticism is based on misunderstanding; in this particular instance you can rely on it.

It's notable that AngularJS includes automatic escaping by default. If they wrote JQuery from scratch today, I expect JQuery would also include this.

One of the reasons not to do HTML escaping in the REST API is that you may have a non-HTML client consuming the API. In that case you definitely don't want HTML escaping to be applied.

It is important you return JSON using the correct Content-Type header (application/json) to avoid API misuse attacks.

Comment: +1 for understanding what XSS actually is. Thank you!

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the scenario of API misuse. i.e. I send you a link to the REST API, which returns "not html" (except that it does have HTML / script, thats the point of XSS). Sure, the API should never be browsed to, but that's the point - the attacker doesnt play by your rules.

Comment: @AviD Verify if the request is coming from an Ajax request. Done, done, and problem solved.

Comment: @AviD if you return JSON with the correct Content-Type header then a modern browser will never interpret it as script. I have edited my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Yup, now I can feel good about upvoting this :-)

Comment: I've written such an API a long time ago, the solution for xss is simple: [createTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode).

Comment: I agree for the most part,  but referring to "untrusted input" bothers me a whole lot.  You should say "escaping all output"  or "untrusted output".

Comment: Can i use jquery Encoder available at https://github.com/chrisisbeef/jquery-encoder?

Comment: What about the situation when same JSONis consumed by some other application in your system that think input has been already sanitized? It may display some data without escaping HTML characters, for instance.

Comment: @dzieciou - I think you already know the answer to that. Obviously, there will be a vulnerability. Just the same as if you had messed up sanitisation anywhere else in your app.

Comment: @paj28, so "you can't rely on client-side control for security", which is something opposite you wrote in your answer. How is my situation different from the situation in your answer?

Comment: @dzieciou - if you correctly escape HTML if your front-end - and everywhere in your front-end - then you can rely on client-side controls to stop XSS in this particular circumstance. If your XSS escaping is missing - even in just one field - then you can no longer rely on it. What I'm trying to say, is that this overall approach does work - but you have to get the details right.

Comment: @dzieciou I think it's enough to simply state in API documentation that "this field requires client-side sanitizing".

Comment: Any programmer worth his salt will never trust client side input in server side code, ever.  Scrubbing client-side is so that the client can detect issues before it tries to communicate so it can provide immediate feedback.  Client side scrubbing is never an acceptable only line of defense.

Comment: @Physics-Compute - Good. Any reason you're telling me that? Perhaps you think that client-side escaping which I advise above is the same as client-side validation?

Comment: @Physics-Compute that isn't an appropriate comment for the question. The server should definitely sanitise its inputs to protect _itself_ (so if it stores data in a SQL database it should sanitise for that) but it shouldn't necessarily sanitise for every rendering vulnerability any possible client of its could experience. _That's_ the context of this question.